# Paginating Merged Element Queries

Tags: entries, pagination, merge

I really want something like this to work but the merge function turns Elements into Arrays. I've managed to work around it other times but what's the best practice to combine two entry sets and then paginate?

```
{% set cat1 = craft.categories.group("catAttributes").slug('diabetic').one %}

{% set firstEntries = craft.entries.section("cats").relatedTo([cat1]) %}

{% set secondEntries = craft.entries.section("cats").showInOtherOnCatsWithNeeds('1') %}

{% set allEntries = firstEntries | merge(secondEntries) %}

{% paginate allEntries.limit(12) as pageInfo, pet %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it currently:

```
{% set cat1 = craft.categories.group("catAttributes").slug('diabetic').one %}

{% set firstEntries = craft.entries.section("cats").relatedTo([cat1]).ids() %}

{% set secondEntries = craft.entries.section("cats").showInOtherOnCatsWithNeeds('1').ids() %}

{% set allEntries = firstEntries | merge(secondEntries) %}

{% set posts = craft.entries.id( allEntries ) %}

{% paginate posts.limit(12) as pageInfo, pet %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're correct in how you currently do it. You can't merge Element Queries, you can merge IDs (or any array of anything, really). 
The only thing you should remove, is the `all` when settings `posts`, because `paginate` expects an element query, not an array of elements.

Comment: You are correct! I didn't test the code before posting so I'll go ahead and edit that.

Comment: I just wasn't sure if there was some sexy way to combine both queries into a single line instead

Comment: I don’t think there’s a way to combine relatedTo with a custom field condition and achieve what you want to achieve.